# Printing all matches in a line using regular expression in awk

Tags: linux, awk

Say i have a line:

Terminal="123" Pwd="567"

I want to select only number portion using awk

```
awk 'match($1, /[0-9]+/){print substr($1, RSTART, RLENGTH)};match($2, /[0-9]+/){print   
substr($2, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' file
```

This gives the desired result.

123 567.

However there must be other better way to select both numbers without writing two match statements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a nice little solution with `awk`:

```
awk '{gsub("[^0-9]+"," "); print}'
```

Just converts all consecutive non-digit characters into one space, so it leaves one space before the digit sequence `123`.

Comment: What do you mean by `using an extension of classic awk`? You don't need the `$0`s in the script, by the way.

Comment: Following the [AWK tutorial of grymoire](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-46), `gsub` is said as an extension of gawk and gawk. I don't know anything else on that subject ... I can remove this detail if confusing.

Comment: @EdMorton Ok I have checked what is the difference. As most current OS use gawk in place of awk, a call of awk or gawk is the same thing. I remove the mention for clarity, thanks for your whole remark btw.

Comment: gsub() is not an extension, it's a basic part of the awk language supported by all awks except possible old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk on Solaris). If a tutorial says it's a gawk extension, get a new tutorial. I would definitely not assume a call to awk or gawk is the same thing as it is very often not the case, e.g. on Solaris or OSX or many other platforms.

Answer (score 3):

does grep work for you?

```
kent$  echo 'Terminal="123" Pwd="567"'|grep -o '[0-9]\+'
123
567
```

quick and dirty with awk:

```
awk -F'[^0-9]*' '{$1=$1}7'
```

test:

```
kent$  awk -F'[^0-9]*' '{$1=$1}7'<<< 'Terminal="123" Pwd="567"'
 123 567
```

or:

```
kent$  awk '{gsub(/[^0-9 ]/,"")}7'<<< 'Terminal="123" Pwd="567"'
123 567
```

Comment: yeah thanks another alternative. But i'm looking for something in awk.

Comment: @user1502952 added awk solution

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do it with awk. We set the field separator to `"`

```
$ echo 'Terminal="123" Pwd="567"' | awk -F\" '{print $2, $4}'
123 567
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem but my patterns were more complex so I couldn't brush off my problems with `gsub` or such. I wrote a recursive function and a wrapper to it. It finds multiple matches in one variable and prints them out separated with a space:

```
awk '
    function rec_wrap(str) 
    {
        matches="" 
        return rec_func(str)
    }
    function rec_func(str2)
    {
        where=match(str2, /RE/)
        if(where!=0) {
            matches=(matches substr(str2, RSTART, RLENGTH) " ") 
            rec_func(substr(str2, RSTART+RLENGTH, length(str2)))
        }    
        return matches
    }
    {print rec_wrap($1)}
' file.txt
```

The wrapper `rec_wrap` is needed to empty the variable `matches`. Function `match` writes the position and length of the leftmost match to variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` and the match is extracted with `substr` and appended to variable `matches`. Then the function `rec_func` calls itself with the rest of the string `str2` as parameter until `match` fails to find anymore matches.